# How can i append content to my html page and refresh the DOM without refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm append data to a table and datatables plugins dont recognize the appended data

```
<javascript>$(document).refresh</javascript>
```

Maybe there is something like document.refresh?

Comment: The dom refreshes automatically when html is added to it. How are you currently adding data to the dom?

Comment: Can you provide all the code you are using for this action?

Comment: This should be tagged with jQuery or otherwise denote which $-binding library are you using.

Comment: i want to apply data tables for a reformated table with jquery

Answer (score 0):

According to datatables docs: (https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

use **ajax.reload**

first set a var for your datatable:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
});
```

then when you need to reload call this:

```
table.ajax.reload();
```